# zenity --notification: additional button

Tags: zenity

I´ve got a question regarding **zenity**.

What I want to do is display my total data usage of my web-stick for the current day in a message box.
I found a solution using *notify-send*:

```
set name ( vnstat --iface ppp0 -s | sed '1,6d' | head -n1 | awk '{ print  $8 }' );and notify-send -t 5000 "Info" "bisheriger Verbrauch: $name MB"
```

Another method, which allows me to display an icon in addition to the data, is the usage of ***zenity***:

```
set name ( vnstat --iface ppp0 -s | sed '1,6d' | head -n1 | awk '{ print  $8 }' );and zenity --notification --window-icon=/home/rosika/Schreibtisch/work/Downloads/status_on.png --text="bisheriger Verbrauch für ppp0: $name MB"
```

I use *fish* as standard shell. Therefore the slightly different syntax.

**zenity --notification** displays an additional button whis says: *"Do default Action"*. When clicking on it the message box vanishes instantly. Otherwiswe it vanishes
after 10 seconds.

My question is: Does clicking on *"Do default Action"* cause anything other than closing the message box? I don´t want my system to run into any kind of trouble after all.

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using that you get a notification with a button on it? Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because I cannot reproduce this on my machine.

Comment: @  wjandrea:   In order to produce the respective button just type `zenity --notification --text "Hamster"` in the terminal. This is just an example but it produces the button "Do Default Action".

Comment: @ muru: Hi, sorry I forgot to mention my system specs. I am using Lubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, 64bit. So I´ve got the LXDE-environment.

Comment: I don't see that button, just "Cancel" and "OK". I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, so maybe this is LXDE-specific?

Comment: @wjandrea: O.K., thanks for your effort.  With me there´s neither "Cancel" nor "OK", just "Do Default Action" and the respective text of course. Like you said it´s probably LXDE-specific. Tnx a lot anyway.

Comment: Related, but doesn't seem very useful: [zenity --notification: “Do default action” button - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191482/117037)

Comment: @ wjandrea: Tnx. Yeah **notify-send** works alright (see my post). I was just interested in learning about that zenity-button. Alas the link mentioned (https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/notification.html.en) won´t grant me access to the page.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: Does clicking on "Do default Action" cause anything
>   other than closing the message box? I don´t want my system to run into
>   any kind of trouble after all.

Here's what it does, from the `zenity` `src/notification.c` file:

```
on_notification_default_action (NotifyNotification *n,
                                const char         *action,
                                void               *user_data)
{
  ZenityData *zen_data;

  zen_data = (ZenityData *)user_data;
  notify_notification_close (n, NULL);

  zen_data->exit_code = zenity_util_return_exit_code (ZENITY_OK);

  gtk_main_quit ();
}
```

So no, clicking the button appears to just close the notification and exit with `ZENITY_OK` status.

Whether the button shows at all seems to be distribution-dependent - I see it in the Budgie (Solus) desktop but others apparently don't.

Comment: Tnx for the explanation. That´s reassuring. I tried to look it up myself but couldn´t find **src/notification.c**.  Perhaps the respective config-file has another name in Lubuntu 16.04. Like you said it seems to be distro-dependent. Greetings.